# Differentiability of Eigenvalues - Perturbation Theory

Tags: eigenvalues, matrix-theory, eigenvector, differential-calculus, perturbation-theory

first, I have a general question. In perturbation theory, I saw perturbations in eigenvalues and eigenvectors of square, non-symmetric matrices and the calculations were all right but no one ever proved the differentiability of the eigenvalues/eigenvectors in the perturbation-parameter! They just assumed it. So, why is that?

Second, does someone know one way to prove differentiability (at least twice) of eigenvalues/eigenvectors in the perturbation-parameter for those matrices in the perturbation-parameter?

Comment: Do you have a specific reference you are using? Differentiability should depend on the perturbation being used, as the map from coefficients of a polynomial to its solutions is not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Check Tosio Kato's book, *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators*

Comment: I read Kato's book also but unfortunately I couldn't find the case of a square, non-symmetric, real-valued matrix with at least one simple eigenvalue.

Answer (score 19):

The complete reference is Kato's book *Perturbation theory ...*. But perhaps you need only the most basic results. Then see my book *Matrices* (Springer GTM #216), 2nd edition. This is Section 5.2.

Mind however that this is a much more elaborate topic than what you could think at first glance. There are at least four completely distinct aspects:

- On the one hand, the spectrum is always a continuous function of the entries. But this continuity is false in full generality for individual eigenvalues.
- Next, if an eigenvalue $\lambda_0$ of a given matrix $M_0$ is algebraically simple, then there exists locally an analytic function $M\longmapsto\lambda(M)$ where $\lambda(M)$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ and $\lambda(M_0)=\lambda_0$. This is the case where you can compute by hand the derivatives of an eigenvalue.
- Finally, if $t\mapsto H(t)$ is a one-parameter family (a curve) of Hermitian matrices (think to real symmetric matrices), then the eigenvalues of $H(t)$ can be arranged as a list of functions $t\mapsto\lambda_j(t)$ which inherit the regularity ($C^k$, analyticity) of the data. Mind that there are crossings, the list $\vec\lambda(t)$ is not ordered. The statement becomes deadly false for a two-parameter family (a surface).
- However, the ordered list $\lambda_1(H)\le\cdots\le\lambda_n(H)$ is Lipschitz continuous over the space of Hermitian matrices, with Lipschitz constant one:
  $$|\lambda_j(K)-\lambda_j(H)|\le\|K-H\|$$
  where the norm is the operator norm (equal to the spectral radius for Hermitian matrices).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll read your book to get more details.

Comment: Would you please explain your second bullet point in greater detail? The relation between $M$ and $M_0$ and the statement about the existence of an analytic function regarding an simple eigenvalue, is there any theorem to that?

Comment: @xmonetx The adjective "locally" means that the function $\lambda$ is defined and analytic for $M$ in some neighbourhood of $M_0$. The proof is a simple application of Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: Hi, your Hi, for my research I am busy with symmetric matrices. Now, your 3rd bullet means that simple eigenvalues of a one-parameter differentiable family of symmetric matrices  H(t) are differentiable. You say that this does not hold if you have more than one-parameter. Why is that and can you give an example, as I do not see the problem in fact?

Comment: @Koen. I did not write *simple*. The eigenvalues may cross. I wrote *one parameter*. If you have more than one, the differentiability fails. Just consider the two parameter family $\begin{pmatrix} s & t \\ t & -s \end{pmatrix}$, whose eigenvalues are $\pm\sqrt{s^2+t^2}$. They cannot be arranged so as to be differentiable at the origin.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the example you give, the differentiability fails in s = 0, t = 0, this is when $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$ (so an eigenvalue with multiplicity = 2). I wonder if the differentiability also can fail when we have a simple eigenvalue. Do you know the answer?

Comment: @Koen. Of course, simple eigenvalues depend smoothly on the parameters. This was the second item of my answer.

Comment: @Koen I recommend you the book "Linear Algebra and Its Applications" by Peter D.Lax, in chapter 9 he proves the differentiability of a simple eigenvalue and afterwards the differentiability of its eigenvector. I used the answers of Denis Serre and Piotr Hajlasz and the book to proof my case.

Comment: @xmonetx thanks for the tip. Are you also busy with differentiability of eigenvectors/eigenvalues for your research?

Comment: @DenisSerre Your bullet 3: Does the same hold for the continuity of the eigenvectors? I mean the following: In the case that you are working (so one-parameter family of Hermitian matrices), Can you choose also the eigenvectors such that they are continuous? I cannot manage to find a counterexample but I neither can find a proof for this. I can find a proof that they can be chosen left continuous and right continuous but not that these limits are the same

Comment: Consider symmetric matrix M whose smallest eigenvalue has multiplicity at least 2. Each individual eigenvalue is not differentiable, But (in MATLAB notation) is min(eig(M)) differentiable (can assume elements of M are continuously differentiable)?

Answer (score 9):

Eigenvalues are roots of the characteristic polynomial. In the case the polynomial has simple roots, they smoothly depend on the coefficients. Below is the proof in the real case. The argument below can be easily modified to more general situations.

> **Theorem.** For $a=(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $a_n\neq 0$ let $P_a(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$. Suppose that for
>   $a^0=(a_0^0,\ldots,a_n^0)$, $a^0_n\neq 0$ the polynomial $P_{a^0}(x)$
>   has $n$ distinct real roots. Then, there is $\epsilon>0$ and
>   $C^\infty$ smooth functions  $$ \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n:
>  B^{n+1}(a^0,\epsilon)\to\mathbb{R} $$ such that for any $a\in
>  B^{n+1}(a^0,\epsilon)$,  $\lambda_1(a),\ldots,\lambda_n(a)$ are
>   distinct roots of the polynomial $P_a(x)$. In other words, prove that
>   in a small neighborhood of $a^0$, roots of the polynomial  $P_a$
>   depend smoothly on the coefficients $a_0, a_1,\ldots, a_n$.

**Proof.**
Denote the roots of $P_{a^0}$ by $\lambda_1^0,\ldots,\lambda_n^0$. That is
$P_{a^0}(\lambda)=a_n^0(\lambda-\lambda_1^0)\cdots(\lambda-\lambda_n^0)$ and clearly
$$
\left.\frac{d}{d\lambda}\right|_{\lambda=\lambda_i^0} P_{a^0}(\lambda)\neq 0
\quad
\mbox{for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.}
$$
This is where we employ the assumption that the roots are distinct.

Let $F(a,\lambda)=F(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n,\lambda)=P_a(\lambda)$. 
For each $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ we have
$$
F(a_0^0,a_1^0,\ldots,a_n^0,\lambda_i^0)=P_{a^0}(\lambda_i^0)=0
$$
and
$$
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\right|_{\lambda=\lambda_i^0} F(a_0^0,a_1^0,\ldots a_n^0,\lambda) =
\left.\frac{d}{d\lambda}\right|_{\lambda=\lambda_i^0} P_{a^0}(\lambda)\neq 0.
$$
Thus according to the Implicit Function Theorem, there is a unique $C^\infty$ smooth function $\lambda(a)$ defined for 
$a=(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ in a neighborhood of $a^0=(a_0^0,a_1^0,\ldots,a_n^0)$ (neighborhood in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$) such that
$\lambda(a^0)=\lambda^0_i$ and $P_a(\lambda(a))=F(a,\lambda(a))=0$. Denote this function by $\lambda_i(a)$. Hence
$\lambda_i(a)$, $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ are roots of the polynomial $P_a$. Since $\lambda_i(a^0)\neq \lambda_j(a^0)$ for $i\neq j$,
we see that these roots are distinct in a neighborhood $B^{n+1}(a^0,\epsilon)$ of $a^0$, provided $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small.
$\Box$

Comment: @xmonetx My argument works if one eigenvalue is simple and you have no idea what happens to the others. Then it smoothly depends on the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial. Just read the proof and adapt it to the situation you have.

Comment: All right, thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 8):

The eigenvalues of a square matrix $A$ are  the roots of the characteristic polynomial, and are analytic except where their multiplicities change.
Thus if (in a certain open region of parameter space) there is one eigenvalue, 
of algebraic multiplicity $m$, inside a positively oriented closed contour $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb C$, and no eigenvalues on $\Gamma$, that eigenvalue is

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi im}\oint_\Gamma \frac{z P'(z)}{P(z)}\; dz$$
where $P(z) = \det(A - z I)$, and this is analytic in the entries of $A$.  The corresponding eigenvectors (with an appropriate normalization) can be found by
solving a linear system depending linearly on the parameters and the eigenvalue,
and these are also analytic.